# mosquito_sub to jq get value

Tags: jq, mosquitto

I have MQTT mosquitto_sub running on linux bash that outputs this JSON data received from power plug:

```
#mosquitto_sub -t stat/sensors/# | jq -r '.'
{
  "Status": {
    "Module": 52,
    "FriendlyName": [
      "stecker2"
    ],
    "Topic": "sensors",
    "ButtonTopic": "0",
    "Power": 0,
    "PowerOnState": 3,
    "LedState": 1,
    "SaveData": 1,
    "SaveState": 1,
    "SwitchTopic": "0",
    "SwitchMode": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "ButtonRetain": 0,
    "SwitchRetain": 0,
    "SensorRetain": 0,
    "PowerRetain": 0
  }
}
```

How can I query for the "Power": 0 value only? I only need the "0".
I tried with

```
jq -r '.Power'
```

but that only returns

```
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to “drill down”:

```
.Status.Power
```